# GridView cannot show image

Tags: android, android-gridview

I get all application's icons, and show the icons in GridView. The GridView shows them very well, but when I glides the GridView very fast to downward, sometimes lack of two icons at GridView. This kind of situation not often appears, can you give me some advice.

**EDIT :** this question have been asked before, but no answers. [Scrolling issues with GridView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947019/scrolling-issues-with-gridview-in-android)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have solved it, in my situation, in the adapter of GridView that I used these XML to show image and text:

```
<!--  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:layout_height="18dip"  /> -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/iconBackgroundLinear"
            android:layout_width="54dip"
            android:layout_height="57dip"
            android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/app_icon"
                android:layout_width="45dip"
                android:layout_height="45dip"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="2dip"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:lines="2"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

The key is  **android:lines="2"**, when I am using **android:maxline="2"** , it may show above mistake.

Comment: I think that you were just lucky. I have the same issue, without any text, having a ViewSwitcher with plain LinearLayout elements and Shape backgrounds. Seems like a wierd Android bug...

Comment: While this does actually solve the problem for me, it hints at their being something more fundamentally wrong with GridView. Perhaps it doesn't like variable height entries?

Comment: i think only keep the android:lines  value  same,maybe  can relive your question

Comment: It does the trick for me too. I too had a similarly structured gridview with an ImageView and TextView and the text was totally random in length. 
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Didn't solve shit thus solution is as bad as the internet can inform. Don't listen to this shit.

Comment: This is by far the best solution i've got and it worked like a charm. Also needs to set fixed height and width to the parent layout of gridView item.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this problem replaced by

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/big_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/big_margin"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

to

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/big_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/big_margin"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/workoutlist_itemheight">
```

but really i don't know how did  my issue solved.

thanks